# How do I return the value of a tensor from a function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a deep learning project in Keras, and have implemented a sensitivity function using TensorFlow backend, since that is needed if I want to evaluate a model using it.
However, I cannot extract the value from the tensor. I want to return it, so that I can use the values in other functions. Ideally, the return value should be an `int`. Whenever I evaluate the function, I just get the tensor object itself, not its real value.

I have tried creating a session and evaluating, but to no avail. I am able to print the value just fine in this way, but I cannot assign the value to another variable.

```
def calculate_tp(y, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0
    for i in range(5):
        true = K.equal(y, i)
        preds = K.equal(y_pred, i)
        TP += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(preds, tf.math.equal(true, True)), 'int32'))
        FP += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(true, tf.math.equal(~preds, True)), 'int32'))
        TN += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(~preds, tf.math.equal(true, True)), 'int32'))
        FN += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(true, tf.math.equal(preds, False)), 'int32'))

    """with tf.Session() as sess:
    TP = TP.eval()
    FP = FP.eval()
    FN = FN.eval()
    FP = FP.eval()
    print(TP, FP, TN, FN)
    #sess.run(FP)"""
    return TP / (TP + FN)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you can simply create a new tensor with the values
 obtened.

For example :

```
tensor = tf.constant([5, 5, 8, 6, 10, 1, 2])
tensor_value = tensor.eval(session=tf.Session())
print(tensor_value) #get [ 5  5  8  6 10  1  2]
new_tensor = tf.constant(tensor_value)
print(new_tensor) #get Tensor("Const_25:0", shape=(7,), dtype=int32)
```

Hope I helped !

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for. In the sensitivity function above, ideally I want to return a single number, which is TP / (TP + FN), for example, 0.85.  :)  Otherwise, I just get 0.0000E+0 for sensitivity when my model compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so could it be because in your tries TP is always 0 ?

If i try that :

```
y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1])
y_pred = np.array([0.01, 0.005, 0.5, 0.09, 0.56, 0.999, 0.89, 0.987 ,0.899 ,1])

def calculate_tp(y, y_pred):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0
    for i in range(5):
        true = K.equal(y, i)
        preds = K.equal(y_pred, i)
        TP += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(preds, tf.math.equal(true, True)), 'int32'))
        FP += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(true, tf.math.equal(~preds, True)), 'int32'))
        TN += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(~preds, tf.math.equal(true, True)), 'int32'))
        FN += K.sum(K.cast(tf.boolean_mask(true, tf.math.equal(preds, False)), 'int32'))

        TP = TP.eval(session=tf.Session())
        FP = FP.eval(session=tf.Session())
        TN = TN.eval(session=tf.Session())
        FN = FN.eval(session=tf.Session())
        print(TP, FP, TN, FN)

    results = TP / (TP + FN)

    return results

res = calculate_tp(y, y_pred)
print(res) 

#Outputs : 
#0 5 5 5
#1 9 9 9
#1 9 9 9
#1 9 9 9
#1 9 9 9
#0.1
```

It give me a float number, like you want.

Is it helping ?

Comment: You are correct, this does give the correct output. However, I still can't use calculate_tp(y, y_pred) as a metric for compiling my model.